# FIM 2010 password reset customization

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

On the password reset page of FIM 2010, I want to include a URL/link of one of my LOB application. Can we do this?

Aim is to provide user's easy access to accessing applications after he successfully resets password.

Everywhere I see articles describing changing logo, css and pre-defined string resources. I could not see any example telling how to embed custom URL.

Also is there a way to customize using C# include more complex logic or use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it but you can do this with SharePoint designer 2007 , install it and open site http:///PasswordPortal it will be open in designer with its structure. It will have asp x pages in which you can make changes to add your URL of LOB application as hyperlink. Its easy to add hyper link in SharePoint designer.